# ThreadAbortException internal implementation

Tags: .net, multithreading, exception, cil

As we all know, .NET Framework provides a little bit specific implementation of `ThreadAbortException` handling. Means that this exception can not be catch via `try-catch-finally` block. Taking a little bit more deeper look we know that this exception, in fact, is catch, but re-thrown in the end of catch block. (Actually we can prevent stack unfolding by using `Thread.ResetAbort()` method).

But lets take a look on MSIL:

```
    .try
    {
      IL_0001:  nop
      IL_0002:  call       void WCFTemp.Program::Method()
      IL_0007:  nop
      IL_0008:  nop
      IL_0009:  leave.s    IL_0010
    }  // end .try
    catch [mscorlib]System.Exception 
    {
      IL_000b:  stloc.0
      IL_000c:  nop
      IL_000d:  nop
      IL_000e:  leave.s    IL_0010
    }  // end handler
    IL_0010:  nop
    IL_0011:  leave.s    IL_0016
  }  // end .try
  finally
  {
    IL_0013:  nop
    IL_0014:  nop
    IL_0015:  endfinally
  }  // end handler
```

As we can see, there is no instruction that makes runtime to re-throw this type of exception.

So my question is how it is implemented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't have anything to do with IL.  Exceptions are implemented by the CLR, they piggy-back on top of the native support in Windows for SEH (structured exception handling).  The very first code that runs when an exception is thrown is code inside the CLR.  Which then can do what it pleases with it.  Finding the catch block and running its code is just one of its tasks.  What happens after that code runs is up to the CLR.

You can get more insight into this by reading the SSCLI20 source code.  But beware that clr/src/vm/excep.cpp is definitely one of the hardest chunks of code to wrestle though.

Comment: So, let's step over the aforementioned situation.
Runtime pass over the internals of try block and stumbling on exception. CLR runs some code within itself and exception became handled. ThreadAbortException is available from within the catch block and it will be re-thrown when runtime reach some IL instruction, lets say leave.s. Is it correct? Because it looks as the only possible way to implement it without weird workarounds.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  The *throw* keyword is implemented in the CLR as well.  It is intuitively simple, Thread.Abort() sets a status flag in the internal thread state that indicates that it is busy aborting.  This status flag is checked by the exception processing code in the CLR.